# P5 draw some items only once, but keep them rendered continuously

Tags: javascript, p5.js

in P5 I have some drawings that remain static the entire time. It seems inefficient to put them in the draw method where they'll be drawn and redrawn again and again since they're not moving.

I tried placing the static drawings in setup but that doesn't work.

Is there a way to have some items drawn once and then kept statically rendered for more efficiency?

Comment: In all likelihood and without having any details about your use case, just redraw everything on every frame. Are you actually hitting a performance issue? If so, please share more details about your application and describe the bottleneck. If not, you should be good to go.

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply. No, not hitting a performance issue, it was just a curiosity. I'll carry on with redrawing everything.

Comment: after rendering your content try [`noLoop();`](https://p5js.org/reference/#/p5/noLoop)

Comment: Good idea, but there different shapes that I'd like to continue to draw. With you idea in mind, is it possible to have two draw loops? One with no loop the other that loops? Thanks

Answer (score 3):

Sounds like you might be looking for the `createGraphics` function, which allows you to create a buffer that you can draw to. You'd only need to draw to the buffer once, and then you can draw the buffer to the screen each frame.

See [this search](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=user%3A873165+createGraphics+%5Bp5.js%5D) for more info.

You can also learn more in [the p5.js reference](https://p5js.org/reference/#/p5/createGraphics).

Answer (score 1):

you could just put it in the draw function if it's not too complicated. I can render thousands of ellipses moving around without lagging. if you are using a for loop to draw some very complicated pattern then you should probably use the createGraphics function. the reason that you can't put it in the setup function is that if you have a background in the draw function it basically clears everything on the screen every frame

Comment: Thanks for the info. Yeah It was more a curiosity than a requirement, since I'm rendering much less than what you've successfully rendered.

Answer (score 0):

a simpler way is to put it in setup and make sure nothing is in draw